Lemma in proof of Cartan's Criterion (Humphreys' 4.3)
In Humphreys proof of Cartan's criterion there is a step I do not understand: $\text{ad y}=r(\text{ad s})$.

I tried to check this for $\{e_{ij}\}$:
$$
r(\text{ad s})(e_{ij}) \stackrel{r(0)=0}{=} r(\text{ad s}(e_{ij})) = r((a_i-a_j)e_{ij})
$$
Now I'm stuck. The definition of $r(T)$ was with regard to only $(a_i-a_j)$ so I'm not sure how to compute it with $e_{ij}$.
I noticed that $\left[\left(a_{i}-a_{j}\right)e_{ij}\right]^{2}=\left(a_{i}-a_{j}\right)^{2}\delta_{ij}e_{ij}=0$, and with r(0)=0 I can infer that there exist $b\in F$ such that $r((a_i-a_j)e_{ij})=b(a_i-a_j)e_{ij}$ but I'm not sure how to show that $b=\frac{f(a_i)-f(a_j)}{a_i-a_j}$.

$r(T)$ is just a univariate polynomial with coefficients in $F$ so we can plug what we want into it. Thus $r(\operatorname{ad}s)$ is just a polynomial in $\operatorname{ad}\mathfrak{g}$. The most natural way for this to act is surely $(\operatorname{ad}s)^n$ being taken as repeated application of $\operatorname{ad}s$ rather than plugging into each $\operatorname{ad}s$ separately so we simply have $r(\operatorname{ad}s)(e_{ij}) = r(a_i - a_j)e_{ij}$ immediately.
